# Rails 4.2 content_tag to output a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been using content_tag with no issues to output div's or unordered lists etc. With that said, I can't figure out how to get content_tag to work with tables. I get quirky results. Ive seen similar questions mentioning that you have to use concat.

At a very basic level if I try something like this in a method:

```
def mymethod(item)
    content = ""

    content << content_tag(:table, :class => "table-striped") do

      concat(content_tag(:thead)) do
         headlabel = ["Header1","Header2"]
         concat(content_tag(:tr)) do
           headlabel.each do |hlabel|
             concat(content_tag(:th, hlabel))
           end
         end
      end

    end # end content_tag table

    return content.html_safe

end
```

This will be returned. The thead is empty

```
<table class="table-striped">
    <thead>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you have nested calls to concat?

Comment: Why do you define a method for this instead of coding the table in a view or partial?

Comment: I assumed with tables I ahd to do that. If I remove the nested call to concat I get the same results

This would produce the same result
`def mymethod(item)
      content = ""
  
      content << content_tag(:table, :class => "table-striped") do
  
        concat(content_tag(:thead)) do
           headlabel = ["Header1","Header2"]
           content_tag(:tr) do
             headlabel.each do |hlabel|
               content_tag(:th, hlabel)
             end
           end
        end
  
      end # end content_tag table
  
      return content.html_safe
  
  end`

Comment: Yes its easy enough to do in a view but I was trying not to duplicate code. it would be reused in different views

Comment: kjmagic13 partial is definitely an option thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex nesting with the `content_tag` helper is not ideal. When you nest multiple instances of the same HTML tag, only the last tag will be rendered, hence the need to concatenate. If you refactor like this, your thead will appear as expected:

```
content_tag(:thead) do
    headlabel = ["Header1","Header2"]
     content_tag(:tr) do
       headlabel.each do |hlabel|
         concat(content_tag(:th, hlabel))
    end
  end
end
```

In order to simplify your code and make it more readable, I would offer two options.

1. If the data in your table is simple, i.e it doesn't contain a bunch of conditional code, just use a standard erb partial and render it as needed. It's more readable and just as reusable as a helper method.
2. If your code is complex, with many conditionals and loops. Create a decorator class for your model. The quickest way is with the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) and it will allow you to write your presentation-logic OOP style and make testing much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response.

Comment: I up voted this as the answer since it did answer the question. Not sure why it doesn't show.